# Python multiprocessing memory leak with enthought canopy?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, enthought

```
def print_square(i):
    print str(i*i)

from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(1)
for i in range(10):
    p.apply_async(print_square, args=(i,))
p.close()
p.join()
```

spawns infinite processes and crashes my machine on Windows 8 with 64 bit canopy on python 2.7. Why?

Comment: Doesn't crash for me.

Comment: Double check your indents to make sure print_square ONLY prints i*i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, since there is no fork, multiprocessing spawns a new process, runs python and imports the calling module.

If importing the calling module itself spawns a new process, then you'll fork-bomb yourself. To prevent that from happening put the code that spawns a new process inside

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

This works since code inside the `if-statement` is not executed when the module is imported.

There is a warning about this in the docs. See the section entitled 
[Safe importing of main module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows).

---

So use

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def print_square(i):
    print str(i * i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(1)
    for i in range(10):
        p.apply_async(print_square, args=(i,))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Ok, this no longer fork bombs me, but now print_square never gets called. Any ideas?

Comment: The code posted above should run fine if run from the command line: `python test.py`. Is that how you are running it?